# How can I extract model components from glmerMod objects if $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Tags: list, function, glm, lme4

I'd like to extract the model call for a list of models. The list includes both glm and glmm.

It seems like this works for glm objects, but not for glmerMod objects

```
gm1 <- glm(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period,
             data = cbpp, family = binomial)

gm1$call
>glm(formula = cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period, family = binomial, 
    data = cbpp)

gm2 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
             data = cbpp, family = binomial)

gm2$call
>Error in gm2$call : $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

I can see when I click on the glmerMod objects in the rstudio environment pane that the object does appear to have a call value associated with it.

Is there a way I could extract this information from both types of models using the same function? This would be my preference becasue I'm hoping to set it up as an lapply function to apply to a list of models.

```
models <- list(gm1, gm2)

calls <- lapply(models, function(x) x$call)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `summary()` at all.

`getCall(lmm)` and `getCall(lm)` both work. (If you dig into this you'll see that the default method for `getCall` is just `getElement(., "call")`; `getElement` is a utility function that looks for an element as *either* a list element (`$...`) or an S4 slot (`@...`).)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the call with `summary(gm2)$call`

I imagine something like this would work:

```
library(lme4)
head(iris)

lmm<-lmer(Petal.Length~Petal.Width+(1|Species),data=iris)
lm<-lm(Petal.Length~Petal.Width+Species,data=iris)

lm$call

summary(lmm)$call

getcall<-function(x){if(class(x)=="lmerMod"|class(x)=="glmerMod"){return(summary(x)$call)}else{return(x$call)}}


getcall(lm)
## lm(formula = Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species, data = iris)

getcall(lmm)
## glmer(formula = Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + (1 | Species), data = iris, 
    family = Gamma)
```

Now add your `lapply` code:

```
models <- list(lm, lmm)

calls <- lapply(models, getcall)
calls

## [[1]]
## lm(formula = Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species, data = iris)

## [[2]]
## glmer(formula = Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + (1 | Species), data = iris, 
    family = Gamma)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now that I've played around with it, one edit I would make is that summary(lm)$call actually works for both lm and lmm, so the getcall function actually doesn't need different methods for different classes